# Как можно получить ASCII-код Character в Swift?

Tags: swift4, ascii

```
let a = Character("A")
let aAscii: Int = // ???:
let bAccii = aAscii + 1
```

Как получить в Swift ASCII-код значения типа Character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используйте unicodeScalars:

```
let aAscii: UInt32? = a.unicodeScalars.first?.value
```

Так как символ может состоять из нескольких кодов, такое усложнение. Пример:

```
"a" это [98]
"‍‍‍" это [128105, 8205, 128105, 8205, 128103, 8205, 128103]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант еще возможен:

```
let char: Character = "a"

if let code = String(char).utf8.first {
    print(code) // 97
}
```

Для одного Character такой способ может и не выглядит сильно проще, но если нужно преобразовать не один символ, а целую строку в ASCII-коды, то этот вариант точно будет удобнее:

```
let str = "abc"

for code in str.utf8 {
    print(code) // 97, 98, 99
}
```

Comment: note: для обратной операции (т.е. получить str/char из ascii) - см.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354549/swift-how-to-get-string-from-ascii-code